# Sendmail has at least a 5 second delay before accepting emails. On Ubuntu, not Redhat

Tags: ubuntu, sendmail

I configured a fresh install of an Ubuntu 22 server that runs Sendmail.  There is at least a constant 5 second, between when I send an email to port 25 and when sendmail responds with it's "SMTP Sendmail greeting" and starts accepting the email. The output of the TCPDUMP is shown below.  Older versions of Ubuntu different computers that I have, show a similar issue, running Sendmail 8.15.2.

This does not happen on my old Redhat 7 email server, running Sendmail 8.14.7   I don't know if this is a Sendmail or OS issue.  I would have to configure a new Redhat 9 server to compare with.  Something that I would like to avoid doing.  Thanks for any suggestions. This delay will annoy people running Thunderbird, as Thunderbird display a popup sending bar progress window (Outlook hides it).  Thunderbird users will not be happy, if I install a new server that is clearly worse than the old one!  Thanks.

tcpdump -v host xxx.psfc.mit.edu

17:09:31.959120 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 127, id 45733, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
xxx.psfc.mit.edu.59375 > psfcmail-test.psfc.mit.edu.smtp: Flags [.], cksum 0x00b3 (correct), ack 1, win 8212, length 0

17:09:36.996785 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 10232, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 240)
psfcmail-test.psfc.mit.edu.smtp > xxx.psfc.mit.edu.59375: Flags [P.], cksum 0xee78 (incorrect -> 0xbf0f), seq 1:201, ack 1, win 502, length 200: SMTP, length: 200
220 psfcmail-test.psfc.mit.edu ESMTP Sendmail 8.15.2/8.15.2/Debian-22ubuntu3; Tue, 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

5s delay makes ident queries the fist suspect (see sendmail FAQ) and DNS resolver problem the second.

- In modern sendmail configuration 5s is used as default timeout for ident queries.
- It takes usually 5s to send DNS query to second DNS resolver when the first does not respond.

[Sendmail-FAQ: Why do connections to the SMTP port take such a long time?](https://www.proofpoint.com/us/sendmail/faq#v8-12)

Comment: Fantastic find, thanks!   I added this:
define(`confTO_IDENT', `timeout')
Much much appreciated!